Return all columns for duplicates using a group by subquery and grouping by 2 columns
I have this query that will return all duplicate rows based on a group by subquery.  The group by is using only 1 column.
select *
from "*original_item_master" i
where "ItemStatus" != 'Inactive'  and 
 "ManufacturePartNBR" in (
    select "ManufacturePartNBR"
    from "*original_item_master" i
    group by "ManufacturePartNBR"
    having count (*) > 1 )
order by "ManufacturePartNBR" asc

I need to do the group by using 2 columns but it's not working.  This is what I've tried.
select *
from "*original_item_master" i
where "ItemStatus" != 'Inactive'  and 
  "ManufacturePartNBR" , "ManufactureNM" in (
    select "ManufacturePartNBR", "ManufactureNM" 
    from "*original_item_master" i
    group by "ManufacturePartNBR", "ManufactureNM" 
    having count (*) > 1 )
order by "ManufacturePartNBR" asc 


Try EXISTS instead of IN.

Or, ("ManufacturePartNBR" , "ManufactureNM") IN (SELECT .... Optional ANSI/SQL feature.

@jarlh your second comment worked.  Thanks!

You can do with an EXISTS subselect, like
select *
from "*original_item_master" i
where "ItemStatus" != 'Inactive'  and 
  exists (
    select 1 
    from "*original_item_master" i2
    where i."ManufacturePartNBR" = i2."ManufacturePartNBR" and i."ManufactureNM" = i2."ManufactureNM"
    group by i2."ManufacturePartNBR", i2."ManufactureNM" 
    having count (*) > 1 )
order by "ManufacturePartNBR" asc 

This is a good idea, because EXISTS searches for the first match, so it's a good practice to use it instead of IN. Alternatively, you can:
select *
from "*original_item_master" i
where "ItemStatus" != 'Inactive'  and 
  ("ManufacturePartNBR" , "ManufactureNM") in (
    select "ManufacturePartNBR", "ManufactureNM" 
    from "*original_item_master" i
    group by "ManufacturePartNBR", "ManufactureNM" 
    having count (*) > 1 )
order by "ManufacturePartNBR" asc 

but that will possibly be less performant.
